# can not install ghc-exactprint

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install several packages as following:

```
stack install apply-refact hlint stylish-haskell hasktags hoogle
```

and I've got the following error:

```
ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2: configure
ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2: build
Progress 1/2

--  While building package ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2 using:
      /home/developer/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/developer/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2.log

    Configuring ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2...
    Preprocessing library for ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2..
    Building library for ghc-exactprint-0.5.8.2..
    [ 1 of 13] Compiling Language.Haskell.GHC.ExactPrint.Types ( src/Language/Haskell/GHC/ExactPrint/Types.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Language/Haskell/GHC/ExactPrint/Types.o )
    [ 2 of 13] Compiling Language.Haskell.GHC.ExactPrint.Lookup ( src/Language/Haskell/GHC/ExactPrint/Lookup.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Language/Haskell/GHC/ExactPrint/Lookup.o )
    [ 3 of 13] Compiling Language.Haskell.GHC.ExactPrint.AnnotateTypes ( src/Language/Haskell/GHC/ExactPrint/AnnotateTypes.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/Language/Haskell/GHC/ExactPrint/AnnotateTypes.o )
    <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libtinfo.so (libtinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same error on a different package, and the accepted answer worked for me. `apt install libtinfo-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that `libtinfo-dev` package need to be installed via `apt` or whatever package manager is used.

Comment: What is `libtinfo-dev`? And how to install it?